# aws how to drop tons of videos in the input bucket, and have the output bucket populated with transcoded versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm struggling to understand something about Elastic Transcoder jobs. I have an input bucket, an output bucket, and a pipeline. I'd like to drop tons of videos in the input bucket, and have the output bucket populated with transcoded versions.

I expected to create a single job for the pipeline that defines the transcoding operation for all files. But as I define the job, it asks for an "Input Key," as if I will have to create a new job for each and every file that I add to the input bucket, but that's insane, right? What am I missing here?

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem you wish to solve?

Comment: You need to connect the S3 buckets and the pipeline.  A lambda will do the trick.  Take a look at this post to see if it helps: https://blogs.rayfocus.com/transcoding-videos-using-aws-lambda-and-elastic-transcoder/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the CLI to specify a list of input files. See the '-- inputs' option.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elastictranscoder/create-job.html